# Insert record into array inside a document in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

Im using Azure Cosmos DB to store data in the following format.

```
{
    "id": "id",
    "name": "Name",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "id",
            "name": "name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Im using Azure Functions and JavaScript to add to this document db, and this is working as expected.

Now I would like to add a new product into the array `products`.
Is this even possible, without recreating the whole document?

I would really just like to send two inputs like this.

**Input 1**

```
{
    "id": "A",
    "name": "Name A",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "01",
            "name": "Item A"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Input 2**

```
{
    "id": "A",
    "name": "Name A",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "02",
            "name": "Item B"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result**

```
{
    "id": "A",
    "name": "Name A",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "01",
            "name": "Item A"
        },
        {
            "id": "02",
            "name": "Item B"
        }
    ]
}
```

Maybe im using it wrong, maybe the `products` should have been normalized into a separate document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this even possible, without recreating the whole document?

Partial updates to a document is not possible. You will need to fetch the existing document, update it and then save the entire document again.

Comment: Thank you, I feared that :)

Comment: What about server-side stored procedures?